# Aggregations not working in Facebook Open Graph Timeline App

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I've followed this tutorial step by step: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/tutorial/

The only problem is when I try to submit an action for approval it says:

**No Aggregations created for this Action Type. Please create a completed Aggregation populated with sample data before submitting for review.**

The thing is a have set up an Aggregation. When I click the **Preview** link it just shows a Loading screen and then disappears. I've checked the Aggregation setup many times with different configuration. Nothing seems to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I hit this too. The docs need addressing here.

Answer (score 2):

Before submitting aggregation you have to add **preview actions** and **preview objects**, **Setup Auth Dialog Preview for Authenticating user** section of this [**tutorial**](http://onlytipsandtricks.com/facebook/facebook-application-development-with-open-graph/) may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

The Aggregation preview dialog had a bug in it for about a week through 11/13. As of 11/14/2011, it's back up and working again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems, but managed to solve it after some trial-n-error.

The solution was to make sure to add all the preview objects required for the aggregation:

1. Create an **Aggregation**
2. Preview the aggregation
3. Add 4 (the number that worked for me, might be enough with 2) **Preview Objects**
4. Add your created preview objects as **Preview Actions**

After this, I was able to submit the action.

*This is pretty much what Hasniain said, but in a less descriptive way. At least, I didn't get it just by looking at his answer, albeit correct.*

Comment: I am using the map for check in. When using this the preview of Aggregation is not working. What i did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is ridiculous, but I was having the same issue and finally had success by clicking between the object and action previews until the standard preview window actually displayed my preview objects, THEN clicking save.  That is, even when it showed that both a preview action and preview object exist, I had to enter, not alter, and exit one of the action or object preview sub-screens until the aggregation preview displayed an object.

I understand that there is no sensible methodology there, but this is how I finally got the og to understand that I had in fact defined an aggregation.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a valid bug that I reported yesterday. Please add your own repros to it, so Facebook devs can update us on what's going on:

Unable to create new Aggregation: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/295741107138424
Unable to submit Open Graph Action: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/162515500520749